# How execute join on c# whit LinQ

Tags: c#, list, linq, join

I need to perform a comparison between 2 lists of the same object and get the records that are different, but I can't find a way to project the result of the query in de last select .

In SQL the query would be the following

```
select * from actual a
join nuevo n
on a.d_codigo=n.d_codigo and a.id_asenta_cpcons = n.id_asenta_cpcons
where (
        a.d_asenta <> n.d_asenta or 
        a.d_tipo_asenta <> n.d_tipo_asenta or
        a.D_mnpio <> n.D_mnpio or
        a.d_estado <> n.d_estado or
        a.d_ciudad <> n.d_ciudad or
        a.d_CP <> n.d_CP or
        a.c_estado <> n.c_estado or
        a.c_oficina <> n.c_oficina or
        a.c_CP <> n.c_CP or
        a.c_tipo_asenta <> n.c_tipo_asenta or
        a.c_mnpio <> n.c_mnpio or
        a.d_zona <> n.d_zona or
        a.c_cve_ciudad <> n.c_cve_ciudad
      )
```

En C# con sql el query seria el siguiente

```
var result = from a in actual 
                         join n in nuevo
                         on new { a.d_codigo, a.id_asenta_cpcons } equals new { n.d_codigo, n.id_asenta_cpcons } 
                         where !(a.d_asenta == n.d_asenta) 
                         where !(a.d_tipo_asenta == n.d_tipo_asenta) 
                         where !(a.D_mnpio == n.D_mnpio) 
                         where !(a.d_estado == n.d_estado) 
                         where !(a.d_ciudad == n.d_ciudad) 
                         where !(a.d_CP == n.d_CP) 
                         where !(a.c_estado == n.c_estado) 
                         where !(a.c_oficina == n.c_oficina) 
                         where !(a.c_CP == n.c_CP) 
                         where !(a.c_tipo_asenta == n.c_tipo_asenta) 
                         where !(a.c_mnpio == n.c_mnpio) 
                         where !(a.d_zona == n.d_zona) 
                         where !(a.c_cve_ciudad == n.c_cve_ciudad)
                         select ¿?;
```

In the microsoft documentation they show examples like the following one, in which in the last select they build a new object with the elements extracted from both lists

```
var q =
    from c in db.Customers
    join o in db.Orders on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID
        into orders
    select new { c.ContactName, OrderCount = orders.Count() };
```

Comment: Select a.fffff, n.nnnnnn does not work?

Comment: well when I use select new {a,b} or select new {a.d_asenta} it returns an object type {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<<>f__AnonymousType0<Undani.Tools.Model.Sepomex.Sepomex.Sepomex, Undani.Tools.Model.Sepomex.Sepomex.Sepomex>, Undani.Tools.Model.Sepomex.Sepomex.Sepomex>} but I do not understand the meaning and I am not sure it is the resulting set of the join.